# Notation in John Lee’s Book

Tags: general-topology, notation

I am working through an exercise in John M. Lee’s “Introduction to Topological Manifolds” and I had a quick question about notation:

> Suppose $M$ is a set and $d,d’$ are two different metrics of $M$. Prove that $d$ and $d’$ generate the same topology on $M$ if and only if the following condition is satisfied: for every $x\in M$ and $r>0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that
>   $$B_{r_1}^{(d’)}(x)\subseteq B_r^{(d)}(x)$$
>   and 
>   $$B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x)\subseteq B_r^{(d’)}(x)$$

What does the notation $B_{r_1}^{(d’)}(x)$ mean here?

Comment: The ball, according to metric $d'$, with center $x$ and radius $r_1$.

Comment: @GEdgar I know this is not related to my question, but could you give me a hint?

Comment: For a hint, show that open sets under $d$ are still open under $d'$, and vice versa.